# How to remove default padding/margin of AlertDialog's title in Android

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am showing a `AlertDialog` which is showing some list data but the title of Dialog and data are not showing in Same alignment there is some extra padding given from left to `AlertDialog's` title and Dialog looks like this :

[image]

Code :

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Search on the basis of :");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(OrdersActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
    arrayAdapter.add("Order Name");
    arrayAdapter.add("Order Date");
    builder.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
            adapter.searchType(strName);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

Can anyone tell me How to remove that extra padding from dialog title ?

Comment: you may use custom title view

Comment: also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074313/getting-default-padding-for-alertdialog

Comment: Did you end up with a solution to this @Kapil Rajput ?

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoMartínezGadea Yes, I did it by showing a custom view in a alert dialog

Comment: I guess that's related with the answer of @user2851150 in this topic. Perhaps you could select it as the valid answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Use this for the setting up the reduce the padding of alertdialogbox
setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Change your line:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
```

and add in your styles.xml with parent corresponding to your theme version.

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```